# Number of nodes in the bottom level of a balanced binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am wondering about two questions that came up when studying about binary search trees. They are the following:

> What is the maximum number of nodes in the bottom level of a balanced binary search tree with n nodes?
>
> What is the minimum number of nodes in the bottom level of a balanced binary search tree with n nodes?

I cannot find any formulas in my textbook regarding this. Is there any way to answers these questions? Please let me know.

Comment: Think of what attributes a Binary Tree has. Every node has a maximum of 2 leafs/sub-trees. If you have 2 nodes, how many nodes do you have in the bottom level? if you have 3 or 4? Try making a formula out of it in dependecy of n and of the height of the tree dependent on n.

Comment: This somewhat depends on how balanced we're talking, and what kind of balance.

Comment: You didn't find the formula in a book, but where did you get stuck thinking about the problem yourself? Did you draw some small balanced trees and count the nodes on the bottom? Looking at complete balanced trees would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that it's a *full binary tree*, the number of nodes in the leaf will always be equal to `(n/2)+1`.

For the minimum number of nodes, the total number of nodes could be `1` (satisfying the condition that it should be a balanced tree).

Comment: He is not asking the number of nodes in a full binary tree. He clearly stated that this is a BST with n nodes.

Comment: I said the number of nodes in the leaf level is (n/2)+1

Comment: my mistake. But still this does not answer the question because the question is completely different

Comment: I still don't understand why a full BT can't be a BST. Also, I started with the word, *assuming* . So, for the case I've explained, I believe what I've said is correct.

Comment: BST can be a full tree. The question asks: `balanced binary search tree with n nodes` and a tree with n nodes is clearly not the same as full binary tree. If this is not clear - create a full tree out of 13 nodes and then out of 25 nodes. Your answer is correct but it answers completely different question. You state assuming, when there is nothing to assume because OP clearly told what he wants

Comment: what I've considered is a subset of the possibilities that come up based on the OP's question. So, I stand by what I said.

Answer (score 5):

Using notation:

- `H` = Balanced binary tree height
- `L` = Total number of leaves in a full binary tree of height `H`
- `N` = Total number of nodes in a full binary tree of height `H`

The relation is `L = (N + 1) / 2` as demonstrated below. That would be the maximum number of leaf nodes for a given tree height `H`. The minimum number of nodes at a given height is `1` (cannot be zero, because then the tree height would be reduced by one).

Drawing trees with increasing heights, one can observe that:

```
H = 1, L = 1, N = 1
H = 2, L = 2, N = 3
H = 3, L = 4, N = 7
H = 4, L = 8, N = 15
...
```

The relation between tree height (`H`) and the total number of leaves (`L`)
and the total number of nodes (`N`) becomes apparent:

```
L = 2^(H-1)
N = (2^H) - 1
```

The correctness is easily proven using mathematical induction.

Examples above show that it is true for small `H`.
Simply put in the value of `H` (e.g. `H=1`) and compute `L` and `N`.
Assuming the formulas are true for some `H`, one can show they are also true for `HH=H+1`:

For `L`, the assumption is that `L=2^(H-1)` is true.
As each node has two children, increasing the height by one
is going to replace each leaf node with two new leaves, effectively
doubling the total number of leaves. Therefore, in case of `HH=H+1`,
the total number of leaves (`LL`) is going to be doubled:

```
LL = L * 2
   = 2^(H-1) * 2
   = 2^(H)
   = 2^(HH-1)
```

For `N`, the assumption is that `N=(2^H)-1` is true.
Increasing the height by one (`HH=H+1`) increases the total number
of nodes by the total number of added leaf nodes. Therefore,

```
NN = N + LL
   = (2^H) - 1 + 2^(HH-1)
   = 2^(HH-1) - 1 + 2^(HH-1)
   = 2 * 2^(HH-1) - 1
   = (2^HH) - 1
```

Applying the mathematical induction, the correctness is proven.

`H` can be expressed in terms of `N`:

```
N = (2^H) - 1        // +1 to both sides
N + 1 = 2^H          // apply log2 monotone function to both sides
log2(N+1) = log2(2^H)
          = H * log2(2)
          = H
```

The direct relation between `L` and `N` (which is the answer to the question asked) is:

```
L = 2^(H - 1)                 // replace H = log2(N + 1)
  = 2^(log2(N + 1) - 1)
  = 2^(log2(N + 1) - log2(2))
  = 2^(log2( (N + 1) / 2 ))
  = (N + 1) / 2
```

For Big O analysis, the constants are discarded, so the Binary Search Tree lookup time complexity (i.e. `H` with respect to the input size `N`) is `O(log2(N))`. Also, keeping in mind the formula for changing the logarithm base:

```
log2(N) = log10(N) / log10(2)
```

and discarding the constant factor `1/log10(2)`, where instead of `10` one can have an arbitrary logarithm base, the time complexity is simply `O(log(N))` regardless of the chosen logarithm base constant.

Comment: so, that means that the number of the leaves is linear from the total number of nodes. that means that the BFS will require O(N) space complexity. is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answers from my professor.

> 1) Maximum number of nodes at the last level: **⌈n/2⌉**
>
> If there is a balanced binary search tree with 7 nodes, then the answer would be ⌈7/2⌉ = 4 and for a tree with 15 nodes, the answer would be ⌈15/2⌉ = 8.
>   But what is troubling is the fact that this formula gives the right answer only when the last level of a balanced tree is **completely** filled from left to right.
>   For example, a balanced binary search tree with 5 nodes, the above formula gives an answer of 3 which is not true because a tree with 5 nodes can contain a maximum nodes of 4 nodes at the last level. **So I am guessing he meant full balanced binary search tree.**
>
> 2) Minimum number of nodes at the last level: **1**

Answer (score -1):

**The maximum number** of nodes at level `L` in a binary tree is `2^L` (if you assume that the vertex is level 0). This is easy to see because at each level you spawn 2 children from each previous leaf. The fact that it is balanced/search tree is irrelevant. So you have to find the biggest `L` such that `2^L < n` and subtract it from `n`. Which in math language is:

[image]

**The minimum number** of nodes depends on the way you balance your tree. There can be height-balanced trees, weight-balanced trees and I assume other balanced trees. Even with height balanced trees you can define what do you mean by a balanced tree. Because technically a tree of `2^N` nodes that has a hight of `N + 2` is still a balanced tree.